# Bitmap b= (Bitmap) bundle.get("data"); confusion , android

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap

```
Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
Bitmap b = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");
iv.setImageBitmap(b);
```

1. What does bundle.get("data"); mean ?
2. If "data" is the key , how do we get to know that this is the key used automatically in intents , is there no other key?
3. Do all action intents have the same key? i.e "data" key
4. In intents , the data is always sent in the form of bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: A Bundle is a kind of Map where you store a value to a specified key. But in contrast to Map Bundles are parcelable and only accept parcelable or seriazable values so they can be transfered between processes which is very important in Android since every app runs in an own process (there are some exceptions to it like apps that share the same userId but they are the minority).

2: What is behind the keys or what keys are used depends on the component providing you with the Bundle. For system components like the [MediaStore](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html) for example, there are usually contstants or a documentation explaining what to expect in a bundle.

3: No, see above. Developers are free to put values at whatever keys they want. You only know what to expect if they document it or you browse trough the code if possible.

4: Not always. You can also pass an URI and a mime type with an intent. But for most cases Bundles are used. An URI could for example point to an content provider that you then query with the provided URI for the actual data.

Comment: Thanks for help bro, facing alot of problems as a beginner

Comment: a `Bundle` can also store primitive data types as byte, short, integer etc, arrays of them and some other classes like `Size`, `SizeF`, `IBinder`

Comment: Where i can find the documentation that says , the key for "ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE" intent is "data"

Comment: Ok so found it , "When you use ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE to capture a photo, the camera may also return a downscaled copy (a thumbnail) of the photo in the result Intent, saved as a Bitmap in an extra field named "data"."